# How to use elasticsearch or Kibana console in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

Maybe it is simple question since cannot find anything regarding this. I am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es guide which talks about creating a lambda function that sends s3 data to es.

I've followed all the steps and at checking stage. I've uploaded my sample.log file to s3 and want to check if it had been successfully added to elasticsearch.

I cannot access it from cmd or anaconda prompt using curl

```
curl GET "https://path/lambda-index/_search?pretty"
```

outputs 
`curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: GET`

and

```
curl GET "https://path/lambda-index/_search?pretty"
```

outputs

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: GET
curl: (7) Failed to connect to vpc-es-logs-wxmypa5bsx4dqutl7h46qsl3qa.ap-northeast-2.es.amazonaws.com port 443: Timed out
```

I want to now use elasticsearch console or kibana however I do not know how to access it. I've tried going to VPC endpoint and Kibana url posted in elasticsearch domain page and it won't connect.

How can I use es console?

**Solved :** After creating new domain with public access it works fine. I guess there were something wrong with VPC, not sure why though(if anyone does know, please explain)

Comment: Go to elastic searc domain -> overview -> grab Endpoint for rest, kibana for console

Comment: @Adiii Thanks for ur reponse. I can only see service overview and when I click it just takes me to https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/ even though I've signed in.

Comment: Are you looking for elk endpoints?

Comment: no just kibana or elasticsearch console

Comment: It still not clear to me but let me post the screen shot as an answer

Answer (score 0):

What I assume that you are looking for the endpoint of the elastic search service,

Suppose you are looking at Oregon than

1. https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/es/home?region=us-west-2#
2. Select domain

[image]

3. Select the the ES domain

[image]

If you do not have any domain

[image]

Or if you feel that you are login or just elastic search then you can search like

[image]

Comment: just like picture below number 3 I see VPC-endpoint and Kibana however when I click them don't work.

Comment: Try to open private windows

Comment: I created another domain with public access and now it works fine, I guess there was something wrong with VPC.

Comment: Thats great you find the issue, you can answer your self or you can accept this if help to let community know the issue resolved